# DataHub installation on Minikube failing: "no matches for kind "PodDisruptionBudget" in version "policy/v1beta1"" on elasticsearch setup

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube

Im following the deployement guide of DataHub with Kubernetes present on the documentation: https://datahubproject.io/docs/deploy/kubernetes

Settin up the local clusten with Minikube I've started following the prerequisites session of the guide.
At first I tried to change some of the default values to try it locally (I've already installed it sucessfully on Google Kubernetes Engine, so I was trying different set ups)
But on the first step of the installation I've received the error:

> Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: resource mapping not found for name: "elasticsearch-master-pdb" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "PodDisruptionBudget" in version "policy/v1beta1"
> ensure CRDs are installed first

The steps I've followed after installing Minikube where the exact steps presented on the page:

1. helm repo add datahub https://helm.datahubproject.io/
2. helm install prerequisites datahub/datahub-prerequisites

With the error happening on step 2

At first I've changed to the default configuration to see if it wasnt a mistake on the new values, but the error remained.

Ive expected that after followint the exact default steps the installation would be successfull locally, just like it was on the GKE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help browsing the DataHub slack community and figured out a way to fix this error.

It was simply a matter of a version error with Kubernetes, I was able to fix it by forcing minikube to start with the 1.19.0 version of Kubernetes:

- minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.19.0